# Is this $\sigma$-algebra lemma true?

Tags: measure-theory

In the 1996 book "Probability" by Shiryaev, there is a lemma on page 145 involving sigma algebras and their intersection with a set.

> Let $E$ be a class of subsets of $\Omega$, let $B\subset\Omega$, and define $$E\cap B=\{A\cap B| A\in E\}.$$ Then $$\sigma\left(E\cap B\right)=\sigma(E)\cap B.$$

My doubt is that $\sigma(E)\cap B$ would be a sigma algebra in $B$, but not in $\Omega$ since we intersect all of $\sigma(E)$ with $B$. I think the correct expression should be $\sigma\left(E\cap B\right)=\left(\sigma(E)\cap B\right)\cup\left(\sigma(E)\cap B^c\right)$.

In case my idea is wrong and this lemma is correct, I would then ask, how is it that $\sigma(E)\cap B$ is a sigma algebra in $\Omega$? Because this is what confuses me from reading the Lemma and the proof since I don't understand how $\Omega$ could be there.

Edit: We have reached a conclusion in the comments on how to properly interpret this Lemma.

Comment: I guess both of the $\sigma$-algebras are meant as $\sigma$-algebras on $B$ but not on $\Omega$, so there is no issue.

Comment: I assume the book defined the generated $\sigma$-algebra to be with respect to the set $\Omega$? In any case, it feels like the lemma is sloppily written. Namely, the $\sigma$'s on both side of the displayed equation would have to mean different things in order for this to be correct. Namely, the "$\sigma$" on the left should correspond to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in $B$ containing $E\cap B$, while the "$\sigma$" on the right should correspond to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ containing $E$ (as opposed to in $B$ because we do not know if $E\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$).

Comment: I agree with both of you. It's not by first time reading this Lemma, but due to how it's written I keep forgetting the left side's sigma algebra is with respect to $B$ and not $\Omega$. Thanks both for the quick reply.